# MvcSiteMapProvider with [Route]

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

I have a controller method with this signature.

```
[Route("clients/{_pmcp?}")]
public ActionResult ClientList(PartyBillingListModel model)
```

The site map node looks like this:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Clients" controller="Client" action="ClientList" area="my" preservedRouteParameters="_pmcp" cacheResolvedUrl="false">
```

The urls look like this.
The optional number at the end represents the page.
Only **the first url is recognised** as belonging to the controller method.

The breadcrumb is only shown for this first route.
How do I correct this?

```
http://localhost:37959/my/clients
http://localhost:37959/my/clients/1
http://localhost:37959/my/clients/2
```

I am using version 4.4.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bug (4.4.10)

Hi,
I have discovered that this was a bug in the 4.4.10 release.
It's working correctly in the version available on nuget today. 4.4.12.

It might be related to this pull request: https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/pull/273

Thanks
Regards
Craig